# Doctrine: Class User does not exist and could not be loaded

Tags: codeigniter, doctrine-orm

I am facing the same problem as descripted in [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4532367/doctrine-not-working-unless-i-explicitly-call-annotationdrivergetallclassnames) but the solution does not work for me. I am using Doctrine 2.1 with CodeIgniter 2 downloaded as package from [wildlyinaccurate](http://wildlyinaccurate.com/integrating-doctrine-2-with-codeigniter-2/). As you can see on the page the ClassLoader is called:

```
$entitiesClassLoader = new \Doctrine\Common\ClassLoader('models', rtrim(APPPATH, '/'));
$entitiesClassLoader->register();
```

I made sure the path is right. I even tried setting the full path.

Strange for me is that `$user = new models\User();` is working. Calling `$this->em->find('User', 8);` I get the error User does not exists.

Any thoughts about that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a wild guess but don't you have to call find('models\User', 8) ? Because your User object is properly in the 'models' namespace?

Comment: wild guess? greate guess! Thanks a lot. I feel so blind :)

Comment: You shouldn't many developers including me make these mistakes, we stay humans :)